# Postgresql Convert SQL XML Coding to SQL JSON Coding

Tags: sql, json, xml, postgresql, jsonb

How to convert XML SQL Coding to JSON SQL Coding.
Example:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME "ORDER", XMLFOREST(PURCHASE_ORDER AS OD_NO)) AS "XMLELEMENT" FROM 
TBL_SALES
```

Now how to convert this `XMLELEMENT` & `XMLFOREST` into `JSON` functions. Please help me. Do we have equivalent `XMLELEMENT`/`XMLFOREST` in `JSON` functions.

xml:

```
<order><OD_NO>4524286167</OD_NO><order_date>2020-06-15</order_date><sales_office>CH</sales_office></order>
```

json:

```
{ "OD_NO": "4524286167", "order_date": "2020-06-15", "sales_office": "CH" }
```

Comment: what JSON output you are expecting from your query as comparing XML with JSON will not solve your purpose because both are different

Comment: @AkhileshMishra 

xml:
<order><OD_NO>4524286167</OD_NO><order_date>2020-06-15</order_date><sales_office>CH</sales_office></order>

json:
{
   "OD_NO": "4524286167",
   "order_date": "2020-06-15",
   "sales_office": "CH"
}

How to write SQL Coding to get result in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Postgresql [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html)
`json_build_object(VARIADIC "any")` and
`jsonb_build_object(VARIADIC "any")`
are semantically close to XMLELEMENT and very convenient for '*embroidering*' of whatever complex JSON you may need. Your query might look like this:

```sql
select json_build_object
(
  'OD_NO', order_number, -- or whatever the name of the column is
  'order_date', order_date,
  'sales_office', sales_office
) as json_order
from tbl_sales;
```

I do not think that there is a XMLFOREST equivalent however.

Answer (score 1):

Here `row_to_json` will do the thing.

You can write your query like below:

```
select row_to_json(x) from 
(select purchase_order "OD_NO", order_date, sales_office from  tbl_sales ) x
```

If You want to aggregate all the results in a single JSON Array use `JSON_AGG` with `row_to_json`:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(x)) from 
(select purchase_order "OD_NO", order_date, sales_office from  tbl_sales ) x
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=22f750148ccb3e05742ba823a3989210)